# unwindSegue slow to dismiss viewController

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, unwind-segue

I am using an unwindSegue created in storyboard to dismiss a modally presented tableViewController.

When I call the unwindSegue in the didSelectRowAt:

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
     chosenItem = items[indexPath.row]
     self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "Unwind Segue", sender: nil)
}
```

the prepareForSegue on this tableViewController and the unwind function on the viewController that will be unwinded to are called immediately.  This is the prepare for segue on the tableViewController that will be dismissed:

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if let vc2 = segue.destination as? ItemsTableViewController {
        vc2.item = chosenItem
    }
}
```

and here is the unwind function on the viewController that will be unwinded to:

```
@IBAction func unwindFromAddCategory(_ segue: UIStoryboardSegue) {
        tableView.reloadData()
}
```

The problem is the tableViewController that is being dismissed occasionally takes several seconds to dismiss.  The model for the tableViewController rows is just an array of strings.  There is nothing happening asynchronously that I am aware of and the viewController that is being unwinded to has no methods that will cause this delay and no viewWillAppear or viewDidAppear overrides.  Having trouble understanding why occasionally there is this delay on my UI.

Comment: Try to wrap your call in a DispatchQueue.main.async

Comment: I tried doing that in the didSelectRowAt method. Putting the performSegue in the DispathQueue.main.async seems to work.  But that's very confusing to me because I thought that call was on the main queue anyway?  I haven't done anything asynchronously here.  But thanks for the solution, it works for me.